# AWS CloudFormation CLI - parameters issue

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have an EC2 instance using which I am trying to execute a CFN script, but I am facing the following error :

```
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Unable to retrieve https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVPC-Parameters.json: received non 200 status code of 403
```

Please refer to my CLI command :

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --stack-name mytestVPC  \
    --template-url  https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VPC.yaml \
    --parameters https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VPC-Parameters.json \
    --tags  https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VPC-Tags.json \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

I have executed CFN using CLI before, but this is the first time I am facing such issue.
My Role has full access to S3 for all resources. I validated my `--parameters` JSON as well and it is valid.

AWS CLI Version  : `aws-cli/1.16.102 Python/2.7.16 Linux/4.14.171-105.231.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.12.92`

When I remove `--parameters` and `--tags` from the command , the command is executed successfully.

It will be great if someone could help me to understand and resolve this issue.

Comment: if you curl on 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VPC-Parameters.json' , does it return 200?

Comment: It will not work because the bucket is not publicly accessible

Answer (score 1):

`--parameters` flag has key/value format like:

```
ParameterKey=string,ParameterValue=string,UsePreviousValue=boolean,ResolvedValue=string ...
```

You can't use URL there. Same for `--tags`.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --stack-name mytestVPC  \
    --template-url  https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VPC.yaml \
    --parameters ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=TestKey ParameterKey=SubnetID,ParameterValue=SubnetID1 \
    --tags  Key=MyTag,Value=MyTagValue \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html)

Comment: You can pass the URL , I have deployed so many CFN's using CLI. This you can refer for example https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/passing-parameters-to-cloudformation-stacks-with-the-aws-cli-and-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I did the following things to resolve this :

- Earlier I had inline policy to my Role with limited access to S3, CFN and EC2, I removed it and granted full access to the S3, CFN and EC2 using existing policies
- Turned off Block public access (bucket settings)
- Made my yaml script and parameters and tags JSON files public

Then executed the command and it worked.

Note : This is not the best practise to do, Ideally the initial settings which I was working with should work, because I have deployed CFN using CLI using the same settings. The ideal setting should be/ must be :

- Policy with limited and necessary actions attached to Role
- Block public access (bucket settings) must be on since your EC2 will access it
- Don't need to make objects (scripts / json files ) public since your role has access to the specific S3 bucket

I will try to raise a ticket with AWS guys and check this and will update this answer asap.